# How to deal with negative depth in 3D perspective projection

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

#### Background

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706796/projecting-3d-point-onto-viewport-dealing-with-negative-depth) asked 3 years ago.  Basically, I'm wanting to re-create a rudimentary first-person graphics engine as a learning experience.

So, say for example, that we're in a 3D space where `z` is representative of depth - `x` and `y` map to the `x` and `y` coordinates of the 2D space.  If this coordinate system's origin is the camera, then a point at `(0, 0, 1)` would be located directly in front of the camera and a point at `(0, 0, -1)` would be located directly behind the camera.

Adding depth to this projection simply requires us to divide our `x` and `y` components by the `depth` (in this case, `z`).  In practice, this makes sense to me and it appears to work.

#### Until...

...the depth becomes negative.  If the depth is negative and you divide `x` and `y` by the depth, `x` and `y`'s signs will change.  We know that logically, however, this shouldn't be the case.

I've tried a few things so far :

- Using the absolute value of `depth` - this wasn't ideal.  Say there's a point `(1, 1, 4)` and `(1, 1, -4)`.  These points will then theoretically project onto the same location.
- Trying to approximate negative values as decimals.  So, if we have a negative depth, we try to map positive decimal number (between 0 and 1), allowing our x and y coordinates to stretch to infinity.  The larger the negative number is, the closer to zero that the representative positive decimal is that we'd calculate.  I feel like this might be a potential solution, but I'm still struggling a little bit with the concept.

So, how do you handle negative depths in your perspective projections?

I'm very new to graphics, so if I'm omitting any information that's needed to answer this question, feel free to ask.  I wanted to keep this implementation agnostic since I feel like this question tends more towards the theoretical aspect of perspective projection.

#### EDIT

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQYsFshbkYw#t=137) identifies the problem I'm trying to solve.  It's a great video and is also what inspired me to start this little project - but I'm just wondering if there was a generally 'agreed-upon' way to handle this particular case.

Comment: I don't have any experience with computer graphics, but do you need to bother about points with a negative `z` component? From what I gather, you want to project `(x,y,z)` points onto the plane `z=1` by tracing a line back to the origin `(0,0,0)`,  so your world coordinates `(x,y,z)` would just map to the "screen" coordinates `(X,Y)` where `X=x/z`, `Y=y/z`. The viewer wouldn't see points with a negative `z` in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  And you're right - if we're working with just a single point, or two points with negative depths, then yes - we'd probably ignore them.  

However, if we're trying to draw a line between two points - one in the field of view, and the other behind the camera, then we might care about where the point behind the camera is 'projected'.  

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQYsFshbkYw#t=137) explains the problem I'm trying to solve.  He does say what the problem is, but I was just wondering if there was a generally agreed upon solution to the problem.

Comment: The code in that video is a little hard to read. I think this basically amounts to trimming any parts of objects that lie outside what's called the [viewing furstum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum), a process called [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28computer_graphics%29). This would be easier to do if the framework you're working with has the ability to intersect lines and planes.

Comment: Cool!  I think I have an idea of how to go about doing this.  Unfortunately, I'm not using much of a framework to do this - part of the fun (and suffering) comes from trying to do all of this myself.  We'll see how it goes, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a point projection, which means that your projected point in 2D is exactly the point where the line between 3D object and 3D camera would pass through the canvas. For positive depth, that intersection is between object and camera. For negative depth, the intersection is beyond the camera. But it's still the same line, hence swapping signs makes perfect sense.

Of course, actually drawing stuff with negative depth doesn't make that much sense, since usually you won't see things behind your camera. And if you do, then you have some extremely wide angle lense, so assuming the canvas as a *plane* in space is no longer accurate, and you'll have to switch to more complex projections to simulate fish-eye lenses and similar.

It might however be that you want to draw a triangle or other geometric primitive, and that just one of the corners has negative depth, while the others are positive. The usual approch in such scenarios is to clip the object to the frustrum, more particularly to intersect it with the near plane of the frustrum, thus getting rid of all points with negative depth. Usually your graphics pipeline can take care of this clipping.

Comment: Thanks for this!  This particular question is centered more towards drawing a line between a point that's in front of the camera and one that's behind the camera - like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQYsFshbkYw#t=137).  That being said, I think I understand what you're trying to say - instead of drawing a line connecting a point in front of a camera to a point behind the camera, we instead draw a line connecting the point in front of the camera to this intersection with the near-clipping pane of the frustrum (which is a fixed positive depth away from the camera), right?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide a more math-y answer for anyone interested.

The mathemetical theory behind this is called [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry). You start with a three dimensional space and then split it into equivalence classes where two points `a` and `b` are equivalent if there is a factor `f` so that `f*a == b`. So for example `(4, 4, 4)` would be in the same class as `(1, 1, 1)` and `(3, 6, 9)` would be in the same class as `(100, 200, 300)`. Geometrically speaking, you look at the set of straight lines through `(0, 0, 0)`.

If you pick the point with `z == 1` from every equivalence class you basically get a 2D space. This is exactly what "perspective projection" is. However, the equivalence classes for points like `(1, 1, 0)` do not have such a point. So what you actually get is a 2D space + some additional "points at infinity".

You can think of these points as a circle that goes around your coordinate system, but with an infinite radius. Also, opposite points are identical, so stuff that goes out on one end wraps around and comes back in on the opposite side. This means that straight lines are actually just circles that contain a point at infinity.

To make a concrete example. If you want to render a straight line from `(1, 1, 4)` to `(1, 1, -4)` you first normalize both of them to `z == 1`: `(0.25, 0.25, 1)` and `(-0.25, -0.25, 1)`. But now when you draw the line between them, you need to go "the other way around", i.e. leave the screen in one direction and come back in at the opposite side. (You can skip the "come back in" part though because it is behind the camera.)

For implementation it is unfortunately not sufficient to map `(1, 1, -4)` to `(inf, inf, 1)` because that way there would be no way to know the slope of the line. You can either fake it by using a very large number instead of infinity or you can do it properly and handle these special cases throughout your code.